# How to launch any application on iPhone or iPad (real device) from terminal

Tags: ios, ios-ui-automation

I want to launch an application from terminal before execution of automation scripts starts.

Answer (score 0):

What kind of Automation framework are you using? If you are using XCode Instruments the app automatically launches before the test starts